# sql command, nested sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have two tables,

1. billing ("columns"(bill_no,item_no))  // bill no can be repeated in the database
2. items ("columns"(item_no(primarykey),name,type,price)

> i want to know any possible query to show me this:

**|bill_no|item_no|name|type|price|**

i want to show *bill_no* and *item_no* of **billing** table n values of **item** table usin *item_no* coloumn

thank you.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to write the query?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with your query, here are some options:

```
select billing.bill_no
, billing.item_no
, item.name
, item.type
, item.price
from billing, items
where billing.item_no = items.item_no
```

OR

```
select billing.bill_no
, billing.item_no
, item.name
, item.type
, item.price
from billing
join items on billing.item_no = items.item_no
where billing.bill_no = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple join.

```
select billing.bill_no
        ,billing.item_no
        ,items.name
        ,items.type
        ,items.price
from billing
join items on items.item_no = billing.item_no
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select b.bill_no
      ,i.item_no
      ,i.name
      ,i.type
      ,i.price 
 from billing b
     ,items i
 where i.item_no=b.item_no;
```